# transitiveMemberOf $filter only works when you are a direct member

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to use Graph to find out if a user is a transitive member of a group (e.g. Bob is a member of Marketing which is a member of Company -- is Bob a member of Company?)

If I do

```
/me/transitiveMemberOf
```

and check the results, I can see Bob is a member of the Company group. However, if I do:

```
/me/transitiveMemberOf?$filter=id eq 'ID OF COMPANY'
```

I get the following error:

```
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "date": "2019-11-13T22:00:12"
        }
    }
}
```

The resource ID in the error message is Bob's user ID.

However, if I put Bob directly in the Company group, the call above works successfully.

Strangely enough, if I do:

```
/groups/GROUP ID/transitiveMembers?$filter=id eq 'BOBS UNIQUE ID'
```

It also works fine, but I can't easily do this from my client without two calls (one to get Bob's unique ID and then this call. Filtering by UPN does not work).

Please advise if the /me/transtiveMemberOf with filter should be working as I expect.

Thanks