# Microsoft Graph: Expand transitiveMemberOf does not return nested groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am calling Microsoft's Graph API to retrieve user data via the `/me` endpoint, using `$expand=transitiveMemberOf` to get the user's groups both direct and indirect.

Before I had been using `$expand=memberOf` to just get direct groups which was sufficient. However, I now need to get indirect memberships aswell.

The problem I am facing is that `$expand=transitiveMemberOf` seems to just be returning the same groups as `$expand=memberOf`.

Due to the implementation, which I *cannot* change, I am restricted to a single API call, in which I also require information provided by `/me`.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Microsoft's API?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Seems it a bug please check this : $expand transitiveMemberOf not supported : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/15517

Comment: Same kind of issue has raise few year back as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58846523/transitivememberof-filter-only-works-when-you-are-a-direct-member

Answer (score 0):

Created a new bug for the issue , dev team will help you to fix that issue - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/16118